# How to configure the artifact version with a parameter and bitbucket feature name

Tags: maven, bitbucket, pom.xml

[enter image description here][1]I have a project that contains several models, I tried to define the version of the project using a parameter when the parameter itself is in the parent properties.
In all artifacts it worked properly, except for the parent's artifact, That instead of getting the name of the version I got the parameter itself:
The parent pom:

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
 </parent>

 <groupId>com.child</groupId>
 <artifactId>child</artifactId>

 <properties>
    <revision>1.0.0</revision>
 </properties>
 ...
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <configuration>
         <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
         <flattenMode>resolveCiFriendliesOnly</flattenMode>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
         <execution>
            <id>flatten</id>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>flatten</goal>
            </goals>
         </execution>
         <execution>
             <id>flatten.clean</id>
             <phase>clean</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>clean</goal>
             </goals>
          </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
  ....
```

and I get this error:

```
could not find artifact com.test:parent:pom:${revision}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some parameters have special "rights". Use `<revision>`  instead of `<test_version>`.

Comment: It didnt work.. Now the parent name is: parent-${revision}.pom.lastUpdated

Comment: Sorry, you also need to run the flatten maven plugin to make it work, it is explained here: https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: And what if the parent dasn't build in the project? I tried to us the ${revision} parameter and it didn't worked. Do you have any solutions?

Comment: If the parent is not built in the same project I cannot use the revsion parameter instead of the version. I edit my question

Answer (score 0):

If you just want an easy way to update the parent pom version of all your module projects use the versions-maven-plugin. (https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/index.html)

To update parent version on parent pom and all modules:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=4.51
```

If change was successfull:

```
mvn versions:commit
```

If not successfull:

```
mvn versions:revert
```

Comment: Thanks, but I work whit bitbucket and I wont that that artifact name will includ the Feature branch name

Comment: I don't see why this should not be possible anyways. You may want to describe this bitbucket issue in you question! If it's because you need some sort of property for the version you could try ${project.version}